# display raw xml in popup window using java when a link is clicked

Tags: java, javascript, xml, jsp, struts

I am using Struts 1.x and jsp as view to display. 
Want to display the entire xml file as it is in a new pop-up window when a link is clicked in jsp. So far I have managed to open the pop-up window but I get a blank window and save/open/cancel links in browser(IE9). When clicking on save I get as 'url.do' but I just want to display the xml content as it is in browser, just don't want to save.

Here is what I wrote in javascript function

```
function viewXML(bcFileNo){
popupwin = window.open("about:blank", "popupwin", "toolbar=no, resizable=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, status=no, location=no, width=900 , height=400");
var form = document.forms['BirthCertificateForm'];
form.action = "/Vista-Web/birthCertificateOverview.do?method=viewBirthCertificateDetails&bCertFileNo="+bcFileNo;
form.target = "popupwin";
form.submit();
form.target = "_self";
}
```

Here is what I wrote in Action class

```
String xmlContent = getXMLContent();
byte[] birthCertBytes = xmlContent.getBytes();
// set xml content
response.setContentType("html/xml");
// write the content to the output stream
BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
outStream.write(birthCertBytes);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
response.setContentType("application/xml");
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline");
```

instead.

Comment: Tried that too but still getting the same output...also tried "xml".

Comment: Updated my answer to include content-disposition inline.  Didn't think that'd be necessary, but just in case.

Comment: Hi, 
Didn't worked bro even after adding `response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline");`. Anyway, thanks for help. Got it working. I was forwarding to some other url in action class after writing using output stream. 
Set the return to null and it is working fine. I am able to view the xml in popup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding the content disposition in the response ?

If not try that first. And it may be useful for you [Content Disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278975/http-response-header-content-disposition-for-attachments)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. Got it working. I was forwarding to some other url in action class after writing using output stream. 
Set the return to null and it is working fine. I am able to view the xml in popup.